# CSS Tableheader Rotation with Word-wrap

Tags: css

I've seen multiple implementations of a rotated Tableheader, and using this one:

```
 table div.rotated {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    white-space: nowrap;
    width:20px;
    padding-left:5px;
    margin-top: 125px;
}
```

Angular2 Template:

```
<div [class.rotated]="index != 0"><span>{{h.value}}</span></div>
```

With long labels however, this doesn't look neat.
Is there a chance to do a word-wrap ?

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `white-space: nowrap;` and add `word-wrap: break-word;`

```css
  div.rotated {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    width:50px;
    padding-left:5px;
    margin-top: 125px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    text-align:center;

}
```

```html
<div class="rotated" ><span>{{h.value}}</span></div>
```